# Select two aggregate functions on the same column using different criteria - performance

Tags: join, aggregate, performance, condition, performance-tuning

Dear stack exchange users, first question here.

The database in question is a service database where a user hires a service. Now I would like to show the person that was hired an overview of how many finished, unfinished, total money earned, total money pending from a couple of tables

I'm a bit worried about if this is the optimal way to write this query. It looks like I should be able to shorten this since i'm selecting on the same tables, shouldn't it be possible to reuse that in some way?

```
            SELECT finished, notfinished, totalamount, areas, pendingamount
            FROM 
            (        
            SELECT COUNT(finished) as finished, COALESCE(SUM(cost),0) as totalamount FROM HiresService as hs
            JOIN ServiceProvider USING(serviceproviderid)
            JOIN BusinessUser USING(businessuserid)
            WHERE BusinessUser.businessuserid = ? AND hs.finished = true
            ) t1
            JOIN 
            (
            SELECT COUNT(finished) as notfinished, COALESCE(SUM(cost),0) as pendingamount  
            FROM HiresService as hs2
            JOIN ServiceProvider USING(serviceproviderid)
            JOIN BusinessUser USING(businessuserid)
            WHERE BusinessUser.businessuserid = ? AND hs2.finished = false
            ) t2
            JOIN
            (
            SELECT COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(Area.name SEPARATOR ', '), 0) as areas
            FROM ServicesArea 
            JOIN Area USING(areaid) 
            WHERE serviceproviderid IN(
                 SELECT serviceproviderid 
                 FROM ServiceProvider 
                 JOIN BusinessUser USING(businessuserid) 
                 WHERE businessuserid = ?)
            ) t3
```

Table structure looks like this:

[image: Model]

EDIT: (accepted answer)

```
SELECT finished, notfinished, totalamount, areas, pendingamount  
FROM ( SELECT  
sum(case when finished = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as finished, 
sum(case when finished = 1 THEN cost ELSE 0 END) as totalamount, 
sum(case when finished = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as notfinished,
sum(case when finished = 0 THEN cost ELSE 0 END) as pendingamount    
FROM HiresService
JOIN ServiceProvider USING(serviceproviderid)
JOIN BusinessUser USING(businessuserid)
WHERE BusinessUser.businessuserid = ?
) t1
JOIN            
(
SELECT COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(Area.name SEPARATOR ', '), 0) as areas
FROM ServicesArea 
JOIN Area USING(areaid) 
WHERE serviceproviderid IN(
SELECT serviceproviderid 
FROM ServiceProvider 
JOIN BusinessUser USING(businessuserid) 
WHERE businessuserid = ?)
) t2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a trick you can use to filter aggregates:

```
select
 --...
 , sum(case when CONDITION THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FilteredCount
 , sum(case when CONDITION THEN SomeCol ELSE 0 END) AS FilteredSumOfSomeCol
```

If you can fit your aggregates into this scheme you can avoid the need for repeated query parts like in the current code. It looks like you can use this trick.